# Find the volume of the solid bounded by $(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2=x^2+y^2-z^2$

Tags: calculus

As Title.

Find the volume of the solid bounded by $(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2=x^2+y^2-z^2$

--

By Spherical Coordinates, I got $\rho^4=\rho^2(\sin^2\phi-\cos^2\phi)$

Then $\rho^2=-\cos2\phi$

How to find the integral bounded?

Comment: I like your use of spherical coordinates. Do you now know what this thing looks like?

Comment: No, it is not a obvious graph...

Comment: As I understand things, it’s fair to answer your own question.

Comment: Now, I got something useful.Because

$\rho^2>0$, $-1 \leq -\cos{2\phi} \leq 0$, then $\frac{\pi}{4} \leq \phi \leq \frac{3\pi}{4}$

Comment: Then
$V=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3\pi}{4}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{-\cos2\phi}} \rho^2 \sin\phi d\rho d\phi d\theta$

Comment: Thanks for @Lubin

Answer (score 1):

As $\rho^2>0$

It must be $-1 \leq \cos{2\phi} \leq 0$, then $\frac{\pi}{4} \leq \phi \leq \frac{3\pi}{4}$

--

$\displaystyle V=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3\pi}{4}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{-\cos2\phi}} \rho^2 \sin\phi \, d\rho d\phi d\theta = \frac{-2\pi}{3} \int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{4\pi}{3}} (-\cos{2\phi})^{3/2} \sin{\phi} \, d\phi \\ \displaystyle = \frac{2\pi}{3} \int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{4\pi}{3}} (1-2\cos^2{\phi})^{3/2} \, d(\cos{\phi}) = \frac{2\pi}{3} \times \frac{3\pi}{8\sqrt{2}}=\frac{\pi^2}{4\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: Looks very good.